# Rails app have not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cpanel, host

I write a rails(4) app and upload that on a shared host .
but my app does not have exist and show me a white blank page.
My host's ruby and Rails versions are so old versions.
I think this problem's reason is that old versions.
I tried to upgrade the ruby version but i cant do that.
How i can fix this problem?

Comment: Your question is too broad, add proper error screens/message with environment info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cPanel Shared hosting is not meant for Ruby on Rails work. You should go for a VPS. If you need something light, try Heruku. They are kind of shared hosting (PAAS) for Ruby on Rails and some other stacks. Plus, they also offer a free plan.

Comment: but this host support ROR

Comment: +is a free host with sqlite3 db?

Comment: A lot of provider supports RoR. But it's always painful to setup RoR in cPanel.